# When I touch my cats upper lip his mouth opens abruptly

Tags: cats, behavior, health

When I touch my cats upper lip his mouth is abruptly opened, and sometimes his jaw moves weirdly when it opens, like it locks in place then unlocks. I don't know if its painful for my cat and I want to know if its anything to be worried about or not.

As far as I know my cat doesn't have trouble eating but yes, when I touch the certain part of his mouth that triggers this it happens. It also suddenly happens with out warning, from him brushing up against things with his mouth and such

Should I be concerned?

Comment: your question is a little unclear to me,do your cat have any trouble eating dry food as in signs of pain when eating,or is it the reaction when you touch the single most sensitive part of a cats body you ask about.

Comment: As far as I know my cat doesn't have trouble eating but yes, when I touch the certain part of his mouth that triggers this it happens. It also suddenly happens with out warning, from him brushing up against things with his mouth and such.

Comment: take the cat to a vet if you think it have pain or problems whith its mouth.cats are experts in hiding pain so have a vet look at it.

Comment: Do you have other cats? Are your cats or just this cat in question indoors?

Comment: I have no other cats and this cat is an outdoor cat.

Comment: While it should be checked out by a vet on your next visit, or if he shows discomfort. But from the description, would it make sense if he was just ticklish? Could be a simple sneeze reflex that doesn't get triggered enough to make him sneeze, but enough to make him open his mouth in preparation.